# Integrating Windows Hello into C++ Win32 Application

Tags: c++, windows-hello

Looking into integrating Windows Hello auth into a Win32 Application with C++. In my research I am only finding C# examples. It looks like one of the core uses in Windows Hello is KeyCredentialManager. As part of a large collection of UWP feature samples that Microsoft provides there is a C++ Sample with KeyCredentialManager. However it requires the Windows 11 SDK.

Could anyone provide information or documentation on the ability to add Windows Hello to a C++ Win32 application with the Windows 10 SDK?

EDIT: Many people implement this in C++ using UWP which we would like to avoid: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/377c092e-4a03-4fd0-8ad2-ce58dfd088a1/windows-hello-using-c?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues

Comment: Often the C# examples are calling C#-branded functions awesomely similar to the Win32 versions (and ultimately call the Win32 function). If you pop the name of the function into your web browser of choice, you usually find the Win32 documentation page in the first page-or-so of results. If you use the C# example code along with the Win32 documentation  you should be able to hack out something that either works or makes a good, well-targeted  Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Let's expand `auth`:  author? authentication? authority? authorization?

Comment: auth = Authentication

Comment: Those aren't actually UWP API's. They are Windows Runtime types, readily available to any classic desktop application by way of, e.g., [C++/WinRT](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt). What's the specific reason you are trying to avoid using them?